# Probability of drawing two colors after four draws

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

You have a bin with 5 balls of different colors: Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, and Blue, all of which are equally likely to be drawn. After a ball is drawn, it is put back afterwards. What is the probability of drawing both the yellow and red balls at least once after drawing 4 times from the bin?

I attempted this problem by finding the probability that a yellow and red ball is not drawn as 3/5 for a single draw. Then, I did  $1-(3/5)^4$ to find the probability that a yellow and red ball is drawn at least once in the 4 draws. Is this correct?

Comment: This is not quite correct: you have found the probability of drawing at least one yellow _or_ red ball, but you want to find the probability of drawing _both_ at least once!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Flip Tack pointed out in the comments, you have calculated the probability that at least one yellow ball or at least one red ball is selected.  We wish to find the probability that ball of both colors are selected.

**Method 1:**  We use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Let $R$ be the event that a red ball is chosen; let $Y$ be the event that a yellow ball is chosen.  We wish to find
$$\Pr(R \cap Y) = 1 - \Pr(R' \cup Y')$$
By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle),
$$\Pr(R' \cup Y') = \Pr(R') + \Pr(Y') - \Pr(R' \cap Y')$$
Hence,
$$\Pr(R \cap Y) = 1 - \Pr(R') - \Pr(Y') + \Pr(R' \cap Y')$$

$\Pr(R')$:  Since four of the five balls are not red, the probability that a red ball is not selected in four draws is
$$\Pr(R') = \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^4$$

$\Pr(Y')$:  Since four of the five balls are not yellow, the probability that a yellow ball is not selected in four draws is
$$\Pr(Y') = \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^4$$

$\Pr(R' \cap Y')$:  Since three of the five balls are neither red nor yellow, the probability that neither a red nor yellow is selected in four draws is
$$\Pr(R' \cap Y') = \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^4$$

Therefore, the probability that at least one red ball and at least one yellow ball are selected after drawing four times from the bin with replacement is
$$\Pr(R \cap Y) = 1 - \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^4 - \left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^4 + \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^4$$

**Method 2:** In the comments, Vadim Chernetsov asked how to perform a direct count.  We count directly.

*One red, one yellow, and two from the other three colors*:  Choose one of the four positions for the red ball and one of the remaining three positions for the yellow ball.  There are then three choices for each of the remaining two positions.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1} \cdot 3^2$$
such cases.

*Two red, one yellow, and one from the other three colors*:  Choose two of the four positions for the red balls and one of the remaining two positions for the yellow ball.  There are three choices for the remaining position.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1} \cdot 3$$
such cases.

*One red, two yellow, and one from the other three colors*:  By symmetry, there are
$$\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1} \cdot 3$$
such cases.

*Two red and two yellow*:  Choose two of the four positions for the red balls.  The other positions must be filled by yellow balls.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{4}{2}$$
such cases.

*Three red and one yellow*:  Choose three of the four positions for the red balls.  The other position must be filled by a yellow ball.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{4}{3}$$
such cases.

*One red and three yellow*:  By symmetry, there are
$$\binom{4}{3}$$
such cases.

Since there are five choices for each of the four positions in the sequence, there are $5^4$ possible outcomes in the sample space.

Hence, the probability that at least one red ball and at least one yellow ball are selected in four draws with replacement from the bin with one ball each from the five colors red, orange, yellow, green, and blue is
$$\Pr(R \cap Y) = \frac{\dbinom{4}{1}\dbinom{3}{1}\cdot 3^2 + 2\dbinom{4}{2}\dbinom{2}{1} \cdot 3 + \dbinom{4}{2} + 2\dbinom{4}{3}}{5^4}$$

Comment: Mr. Taussig, can the solution be performed through binoms $\binom{n}{k}$?

Comment: @VadimChernetsov  Yes, it can.  You would have to consider the cases one red, one yellow, two others; two red, one yellow, one other; one red, two yellow, one other; and two red, two yellow.

Comment: And three red one yellow; and one red three yellow.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis  Thanks for pointing out the oversights in my last comment.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig, Mr. Taussig, you say "one red, one yellow, two others" but the quantity of balls is 5. And "two yellow, two red", but there is only 1 yellow ball and 1 red ball.

Comment: @VadimChernetsov The balls are put back, so the same colour ball can be picked many times. It does not actually say that there is only one ball of each colour, so there could just as well be 100 of each colour, but as the balls are replaced after drawing it does not matter.

Comment: @VadimChernetsov  Since the balls are being replaced, what we are doing is selecting positions for the red balls, yellow balls, and balls of another color.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig, Mr. Taussig, will the probability be $\text{Probability}=\left(\frac{\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{2}+\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}+\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{1}+\binom{5}{2}\binom{3}{2}+\binom{5}{3}\binom{2}{1}+\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{5}{2}^{4}}\right)$?

Comment: @VadimChernetsov  That is incorrect.  However, I have added an additional solution using a direct count, which I hope answers your questions.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig, Mr. Taussig, I don't understand why do you write $\binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{1}$ in the first case when the total quantity of balls is $5$? Therefore, the next binom must be $\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{1}$. Explain, please.

Comment: @VadimChernetsov As I said, I am choosing one of the four positions for the red ball and one of the remaining three positions for the yellow ball. Please read my answer slowly and carefully to make sure you understand its reasoning.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig, Mr. Taussig, Are those positions, you are speaking of about, equal to the quantity of times of drawing?

Comment: Yes, by selecting four times without replacement, we are constructing a sequence of four draws:  One favorable case with one red, one yellow, and two from the remaining three colors is $(R, G, B, Y)$ (red in the first position, green in the second position, blue in the third position, and yellow in the four position); another is $(Y, R, O, O)$ (yellow in the first position, red in the second position, and orange in both the third and fourth positions).

Comment: Hi, can I ask you how you derived this: Pr(∩)=1−Pr(′∪′)? Thank you!

Comment: In words, the probability that both red and yellow are selected is one minus the probability that red is not selected or yellow is not selected.  To confirm this, you can try drawing a Venn diagram.  If you shade the complement of set $R$ and the complement of set $Y$, you will see that what is left is the intersection of $R$ and $Y$.